# How to model neck ruff (clothing)?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, cloth-simulation

[image]

So i have been trying to model a neck ruff similar to the one in the picture, but i'm not sure how to go about it at all, i need to create a neck ruff that can be used within a cloth simulation and appreciate any help i can get. though, if you know how to model a neck ruff, but are not sure if it would work in a cloth simulation i'd like to know anyways.

.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are 2 different questions, modeling and cloth.

About modelling: You can create a basic profile, then give your object an *Array* modifier, then a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode, *Angle* 360°). Extrude inwards, then give it a *Solidify* modifier. Add some edge loops to sharp the edges, it will also allow you to twist it a bit with *Proportional Editing* option enabled once you'll have the modifiers applied (but you can also keep the modifiers and deform it with a *Mesh Deform* modifier).

[image]

You don't say a lot about how you want to animate it as a cloth, maybe you should give your object a *Surface Deform* modifier with a (bit) subdivided plane as object and give this plane a cloth physic. If you create a *Pinning Group*, the less the vertex will be part of the group the more it will be affected by the gravity. Then parent the collar to the plane. It will be much lighter than if you give the whole object a cloth simulation. Needs to be tested though.

[image]